# Pre tag to display code

Tags: css

I shamelessly stole some CSS from SO's `<pre>` tag, in order to have that kind of thing in my site. However, the `background-color` attribute doesn't seem to work: the background is still white. How do I get around this?

My CSS:

```
    pre.code, code {
        font-family: Consolas, Menlo, Monaco, "Lucida Console", "Liberation Mono", "DejaVu Sans Mono", "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono", "Courier New", monospace, sans-serif;
        background-color: #eee;
    }
    pre.code {
        overflow: auto;
        font-size: 13px;
        padding: 5px;
        width: auto;
        width: 650px !ie7;
        padding-bottom: 20px !ie7;
        max-height: 600px;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
        display: block;
        color: #393318;
        white-space: pre;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<code>inline code</code>
<pre class="code">block code</pre>
```

Comment: It looks fine to me, does it still look wrong in this fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/musicalcreeper01/jy9ap7hy/

Comment: You probably have more CSS code that isn't posted that's causing the problem. Can you create a fiddle that reproduces the issue?

Comment: If it looks right in the fiddle, it's probably some other css somewhere in your project effecting it. You should have a look around to see if anything else is effecting it

Comment: I think some class override this background-color

Comment: @Bluefire did you get it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding !important after the background color rules.

```
background-color: #eee !important;
```

This will tell the webbrowser that this coloring overrides any other css rules that may be trying to color it.

**EDIT:**

As Lister said, !important should only be used to help with debugging issues the css. Once you have tracked down the issue, you should fix the offending css.

Comment: You should add that `!important` is a debugging aid that has no place in the definitive page, but only helps pinpointing specificity issues.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing **!ie7** from the rules that use it, and check if that fixed your issue.

Comment: @KeithM - Lines 10 & 11?

Comment: @Prashant oh I see it now, but as it's not on the background-color it would have no change.

Comment: @KeithM Errors may have unpredictable side effects.