# How can I remove the space below image?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I have two images, the body and the ruler. In order to get this result I gave the ruler `bottom:69px;`. Their parent is that with blue background and has `height:auto;`. The problem is, the remaining blue space below the ruler. I can't give the parent a fixed height, because the images are responsive, and they get smaller on window resize and so does the parent. How can I fix this?

Comment: We'd need to see the DOM and relevant CSS. Is there an example of the actual page somewhere?

Comment: please post code or a jsfiddle

Comment: Please provide code or Fiddle

Comment: For those asking for code **or** a fiddle, please don't. Ask the OP to post their code **in** their question and optionally add a working example using a stack snippet or third party resource. The code in question should never exist solely outside of SO.

Comment: difficult to guess without any html and css but display:block to the image should work

Comment: @j08691 - practice what you preach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32543505/pre-tag-to-display-code#comment52944131_32543505

Comment: @JayMee That IS what he's preaching. That question already had code posted. He said don't request code **or** fiddle. Code **and** fiddle is fine (preferred actually). Better still, use a stack snippet instead of fiddle.

Comment: @JayMee - It might help if you actually read my comment which said that the OP hadn't posted enough of his code to demonstrate his problem. That, and stack snippets didn't exist in 2012.

Answer (score 1):

1) Put the two images in a div

2) make that div to have `position:relative`

3) make the top image to have bigger value of `z-index`

4) make both images position absolute and work with the css `top` value to put one image on top of the other, until you cover the blank space

After that, make the images to have a fixed `width` and `height`, and add the `overflow:hidden` to the parent div.

I hop it solves the probem.

Answer (score 0):

I gave to the ruler image the following styles and it solved

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
```